# Soundcloud search only in title

Tags: api, search, soundcloud

Is it possible (like on youtube with intitle: parameter) to narrow the API search so that it only looks at the Title? I am looking for specific songs from local artists, and I often find DJ mixes that have the song title in the description. 
So, are there ANY additional parameters that can be passed inside a q query? And is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not at this time. We're hoping to improve this in the future, so stay tuned to to announcements on [Developer Blog](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog).